BAT file text colors not working after Git failure
I have the following code in a BAT file that I run in a Windows 10 command prompt.
FOR /F %%a IN ('ECHO prompt $E ^| cmd') DO SET "ESC=%%a"

FOR /D %%f IN (%loc%) DO (
    PUSHD %%f
    IF EXIST %%f\.git (
        FOR /F "delims=" %%b IN ('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD') DO (
            FOR /F "delims=" %%s IN ('git status -sb -uno --ignore-submodules=all') DO (
                SET r=%%s
                FOR %%t IN ("%%s") DO (
                    IF "!r:behind=!" NEQ %%t (
                        ECHO %ESC%[33m%%f%ESC%[0m
                        @git pull origin %%b
                    ) ELSE (
                        ECHO %ESC%[36m%%f has no changes%ESC%[0m
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    POPD
)

There is more code to set starting values, but this is the workhorse loop.  Everything works fine as long as the '@git pull ...' command successfully pulls files.  However, if it does not, as in the case shown, it stops displaying text with color and simply echoes the text with escape sequences.  Here is an example (note the command prompt has white text on a black background without the color commands):
C:\Develop\Repo1 has no changes < this is blue text
C:\Develop\Repo2 has no changes < this is blue text
C:\Develop\Repo3 < this is yellow text, the following Git output is white text
From https://dev.azure.com/Home/_git/Repo3
 * branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating 5a4f07a..4d923ef
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        App.config
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
←[36mC:\Develop\Repo4 has no changes←[0m < This is white text, but should be blue without the escape sequences
←[36mC:\Develop\Repo5 has no changes←[0m < This is white text, but should be blue without the escape sequences

Also, note that if a subsequent Git repository is successful in pulling files, the text coloring starts working again.  This leads me to believe there is something happening when the Git command 'aborts' that is affecting how the BAT file (or Command Prompt) treats the ESC character.  Does anyone have any information or ideas about how to fix this?

Try to add 2> CON to @git pull origin %%b command. Unrelated comment: if %%s don't contains any wildcard (* or ?), then the FOR %%t is not needed...

Sorry to say the 2> CON didn't help.  Also, the FOR %%t is needed for the following IF statement to work correctly.  Otherwise, it never goes into the ELSE block.

What happen if you eliminate the FOR %%t and use IF "!r:behind=!" NEQ "%%s" ( ?

I'd try @git... >somefile.txt 2>anotherfile.txt - assuming this works, examine the two .txt files with a hex viewer to determine the actual strings being generated by the #git (as ever, no guarantees...)

The issue with FOR %%t is that without that loop the variable r always has the same (initial) value.  I need the FOR %%t to get r to be re-evaluated.  I'll give the file redirection a try.

Putting the file redirection in the script caused the text coloring to work.  However, I want to see the output that is going into the 'anotherfile.txt' file as output in the command prompt.
Here is what went into 'somefile.txt':
Updating 63e9c26..8a5ad74
Here is what went into 'anotherfile.txt':
`From https://dev.azure.com/DevOps/Company/_git/repository

branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
folder/Code.vb
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
`


I deleted my last comment as it was wrong in its speculation.  The issue is in the output from 'somefile.txt'.  When I removed >somefile.txt from the command, the text coloring stopped working correctly.  When I put that back in and removed 2>anotherfile.txt, the text coloring started working correctly, again.

Unfortunately, that removes all the output about the actual Git changes that are being pulled when the Git command can successfully pull the files.  And when it successfully pulls the files, the coloring works correctly, too.

I was able to get the behavior I want by doing this:
                       @git pull origin %%b > file1.txt 2> file2.txt                         type file1.txt                         type file2.txt.
Not sure why that works and simply allowing the Git output directly doesn't.

For anyone who is having this problem, this is how I was able to resolve it.  Still seems like a kluge though.
ECHO %ESC%[33m%%f%ESC%[0m
REM The file1/file2 stuff is here to allow the text coloring to work.
REM Without this, the coloring stops working if Git can't successfully
REM complete the pull.  For some reason, it stop interpretting the ESC
REM character properly.
@git pull origin %%b > file1.txt 2> file2.txt
type file1.txt
type file2.txt
del file1.txt
del file2.txt

I would try
                    ECHO %ESC%[33m%%f%ESC%[0m
                    setlocal
                    @git pull origin %%b
                    endlocal

to execute git in a subshell
...no guarantees - just a suggestion.

Gave this a try.  Unfortunately, it didn't work either.
